# Nativescript error: Version strings are not in the same format

Tags: telerik, nativescript

I just have installed Nativescript on my macOS Sierra 10.12.12. But when i enter the command: `tns platfrom add ios` I get the following error message:

```
*Version strings are not in the same format*

*#platform add*
```

When I enter the same command for Android everything works fine.

tns doctor gives me the following feedback:

```
*Your components are up-to-date.*

*No issues were detected.*
```

Log Trace:

*ns platform add ios --log trace > log.txt
Error: Version strings are not in the same format
at Object.versionCompare (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/helpers.js:111:15)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/ios-project-service.js:92:25
at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
at FiberFuture.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/platform-service.js:69:47
at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
at FiberFuture.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:565:10)
at .each.platform (/usr/local/lib/nodemodules/nativescript/lib/services/platform-service.js:55:58)
at arrayEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:451:11)
at Function.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:8634:14)*

Comment: Can you paste your package.json of the project? Also if you used the template starters you will have two package files. One for your app and one for the template starter. Another thing to check is what version of nativescript you have installed on the machine.

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed and which version? Also, some third party software (e.g. XAMPP) may cause the command that checks your XCode version not to be recognized - more details on this issue and possible solution here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1782#issuecomment-260272450

Comment: Hello :) my version of tns: 2.5.2 and of Xcode 8.2.1. I also removed XAMPP but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

@Brad Martin
This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.HelloWorld",
    "nativescript-teststudio-variables": {
      "IOS_APP_URL": "telerikmt1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.5.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.3",
    "nativescript-angular": "1.4.0",
    "nativescript-teststudio": "^1.1.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.23.1",
    "babel-types": "6.23.0",
    "babylon": "6.16.1",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.5",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.2"
  }
}
```